# Weird internal microphone level

Tags: sound, microphone, volume-control

This is abnormal properly, when I set this mic level into 40-50% level, the level is too high than normal level condition (usually quite low level). Formely, I set into that level and microphone level is not as high as the level as usual. Can you fix this?
[image: Level microphone is too high or noise, however I set between 40-50%]

Answer (score 0):

Run `alsamixer` from terminal and check "Mic Boost" and "Internal Mic" levels.
Up and down arrows are to increase/decrease volume, while "m" button is for mute/unmute